# How to multiply specific columns in R by scalar

Tags: r

This is probably a very simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to multiply every column (except the first one) on my dataframe by the same scalar. Here is my reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(200, sample(0:100, 1000, rep=TRUE)))
a <- 0.75
```

First I tried this:

```
df2 <- df[,2:200]*a
```

However, this creates dataframe `df2` that's missing the first column.

I also tried using tidyverse with the mutate_at and specifying a multiplication function, but that didn't run at all:

```
scalar <- function(x) (x*0.75)
df2 <- df %>% mutate_at(across(c(2:200)), scalar)
```

My apologies in advance if this is very simple.

Comment: Try `df2[,2:200] <- df[,2:200]*a`

Comment: With Tidyverse : `df %>% mutate(across(-1, ~ .x * a))`. Or `df %>% select(-1) %>%  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x * a))` if you don't want to keep the original 1st column.

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- 
  data.frame(
    replicate(
      5,
      sample(0:100, 1000, rep=TRUE)
      )
    )

a <- 0.75

df2 <-
  df |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(
      # Every column but the first column
      .cols = -c(1),
      .fns = function(x){
        x * a
      }
    )
  )

head(df2)
#>   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
#> 1 58 33.00 54.75 64.50 35.25
#> 2 39 63.00  2.25  8.25 30.00
#> 3 63 18.00 30.00  9.00  0.00
#> 4 22 39.75 46.50 11.25 29.25
#> 5 42 18.75 60.75 31.50  3.00
#> 6 34 46.50 15.00 74.25 55.50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>